# Modifying inserted element inside DOMNodeInserted event produces "too much recursion"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing code for a message board and when the user is writing a post and clicks "preview" it creates a new DIV element that contains the parsed post. I need to detect when this preview element is created and modify its contents. The following code creates infinite recursion in Chrome, Firefox halts after 5 recursions.

```
$('#c_post').on('DOMNodeInserted', function(){
    var $preview = $('#c_post-preview');
    if($preview.length) { 
        $preview.html(applyForEach(funcs, $preview.html())); 
    }
});
```

It's not related to applyForEach because I just added that code and I was getting the recursion error before that but here's the code for that anyway:

```
function applyForEach(arr, s) {
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        s = arr[i](s);
    }
    return s;
}

var funcs = [createGifvVideo, createGfycatVideo, createHtml5Video];
```

The functions simply take a string, call replace on it, and returns the string.

Comment: What does the HTML structure look like?

Comment: @wiesion: The preview looks like this: <div id="c_post-preview">hello</div>

Comment: since , when you added html in preview div , it triggers 'DOMNodeInserted' event again , so its goes to infinite recursion ..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may break the infinite recursion by unbinding and binding event . so it would not go into infinite call.Try following-

```
$('#c_post').on('DOMNodeInserted',DomInsCallback);

function DomInsCallback(){
    var $preview = $('#c_post-preview');
    if($preview.length) {
        $('#c_post').off('DOMNodeInserted');//here unbind first 
        $preview.html(applyForEach(funcs, $preview.html())); 
        $('#c_post').on('DOMNodeInserted',DomInsCallback);//bind again
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose `#c_post-preview` is inside `#c_post`. So when you modify  `#c_post-preview`, the event `DOMNodeInserted` is triggered again. And you catch it again, and you modify `#c_post-preview`, and so on ...

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have nested `#c_post-preview` inside of `#c_post`, but i can't tell for sure, since you didn't post the HTML source. Of course this would lead to an infinite loop of triggering and catching events. But besides that, i don't think you want to applyForEach the content of the post preview, but the one of the post itself.

Consider the following: http://jsfiddle.net/wpb18pyu/
compared to: http://jsfiddle.net/wpb18pyu/1/